# Angular 6 String interpolation not updating DOM whereas innerHTML does

Tags: angular6, string-interpolation

I have events page and event detail page.

When I place `<h1>{{ Eventinfo.EventTitle }}</h1>` to display title, the DOM does not get updated with new title. However, when I use `<h1 [innerHTML]="Eventinfo.EventTitle"></h1>`, I do get the update title in H1 tag.

Why do string interpolation `<h1>{{ Eventinfo.EventTitle }}</h1>` does not work?

Comment: can you please share the component code a s well ??

Comment: You can check the component code at https://plnkr.co/edit/d2P9tPMP2gEg3b2NlMd7?p=catalogue

Comment: in your component code d.EventTitle is not present, from where it is coming ?? and there is only a component code not html. If you want your question to be answered correctly by stackflow users, share the codes which are related to each other

Comment: d.EventTitle is in view-event.component.html and the code for displaying the same is already in my question (<h1>{{ d.EventTitle }}</h1>). You asked for component code and that is what I have submitted at  plnkr.co/edit/d2P9tPMP2gEg3b2NlMd7?p=catalogue

Comment: yes d.EventTitle is present in html but as it is a concept of data-binding so it must be define somewhere in component or coming from services

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I have updated my question with correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try console in this function and reply with whatever data you are getting in console

```
public getEventInfo(id) 
{
     this.apiService.getEventInfo(id).subscribe((data : any) => {
         this.Eventinfo       =   data.events.results[0];
     });
     console.log(this.Eventinfo); //view data in console
}
```

Comment: {
 "events": {
  "total_rows": 0,
  "results": [{
   "EventId": "3",
   "EventTitle": "Hackathon 2018"
  }]
 }
}

Comment: try this <h1>{{ Eventinfo.events.results[0].EventTitle }}</h1>